# Ternary operator expressions and array literal indexing are not evaluated at compilation time

Tags: solidity, overflow

Overflow is there in both cases:

```
uint8 public a = 255 + 1;
//throws compilation error

uint8 public a = 255 + (true ? 1 : 0);
//throws no error although it's equivalent to the previous expression
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, look weird, yet you will have the error when deploying the contract. In the first case, the compiler knows that 256 can not be an uint8 and in the second case, the compiler doesn't evaluate the expression at compile time but at deployment.

Hope it helps!

Comment: WEIRD INDEED! another weird one is `uint8 public a = 255 + [1][0]; //throws no error at compile time`. It looks like if the RValue isn't explicitly the same type as the LValue solidity evaluates it at runtime.